# GC overhead limit exceeded, but memory left

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I got a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

while splitting some strings. Interestingly, neither the memory was used up nor the garbage collector was going crazy: [image: JVisualVM output]

The exception appeared at 11:10, when Eclipse froze the program before actually throwing the exception. So everything after 11:10 may be just noise.

I repeatedly run into this issue in my long-running program but I do not know how to avoid it. Even assigning much more memory does only delay but not stop it.

Comment: Have you tried running with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and then examining the dump?

Comment: I have a dump, but actually I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Hm... for example an unusual high number of object instances for a class where you don't expect it. But there's something else you can do: place an Exception on `OutOfMemoryError`. Now when OOM occurs, you do not only have the relevant stack trace, but can actually use the debugger to inspect input parameters etc at the moment of failure.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for the number of threads exploding at about 10:12?

Comment: No. It is either some artifact of the JVisualVM-Eclipse-Connection after the Exception or something unknown. But it definitely occurred after the exception was noticed by Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You are using stop-the-world GC (probably Parallel Scavenge).This exception is because GC takes too much time, which maybe more than 98% of total execution time. In this case, JVM kills the process as no real work is being done.

The solutions could be:

1. Try another type of GC, such as Concurrent Mark Sweep, which is not stop-the-world GC;
2. Try larger memory, so GC is not that frequent;
3. Ignore this GC time limitation by using `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`, which may cause problems as JVM keeps working on GC instead of real work;
4. As mentioned, dump the memory trace with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and analyze the trace.

A little more explanation why heap is not full but GC over limit (all these are guesses, and more traces needed to make sure the causes): 
this can be

1. too small young generation or most of objects survive from minor GC, so GC happens too frequently and/or to spends long time moving objects (this maybe tuned by changing young generation size on heap, or changing objects tenure rate by some JVM flag);
2. too small old generation size that the objects survived from minor GC cannot be fitted into old generation, which causes frequent major GC (or full heap GC).